Can't install Visual studio(Latest channel)
I downloaded the installer, and it started prepping like it does on any other computer, but when the preparation bar reaches the end, the whole installation exe closes. I went to %temp% and found this log file:
[5/12/2024, 14:11:12] === Logging started: 2024/05/12 14:11:12 ===
[5/12/2024, 14:11:12] Executable: C:\Users\mazep\Downloads\vs\VisualStudioSetup.exe v17.9.34728.123
[5/12/2024, 14:11:12] --- logging level: standard ---
[5/12/2024, 14:11:12] Directory 'C:\Users\mazep\AppData\Local\Temp\61131372aa9e41f7f91d\' has been selected for file extraction
[5/12/2024, 14:11:12] Extracting files to: C:\Users\mazep\AppData\Local\Temp\61131372aa9e41f7f91d\
[5/12/2024, 14:11:12] Extraction took 516 milliseconds
[5/12/2024, 14:11:12] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline ' --layout c:\localVSlayout --env "_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:C:\Users\mazep\Downloads\vs\VisualStudioSetup.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:C:\Users\mazep\Downloads\vs"'
[5/12/2024, 14:11:18] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[5/12/2024, 14:11:18] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0xc0000409
[5/12/2024, 14:11:18] === Logging stopped: 2024/05/12 14:11:18 ===

I didn't know what to do, I expected it to launch the installer layout.
How do I fix this?

Have you talked to the vendor? Have you checked their bug tracking system?

What vendor? there is no bug on the tracking system

In this case it would be Microsoft, obviously.

I have talked to them, but they keep on saying that i have to contact the business team, which i tried to but they didn't respond

Since you've already downloaded the installer and extracted the layout, you can try running the installer from the layout directly. Open the command prompt as an administrator, navigate to the directory containing the extracted layout (c:\localVSlayout in your case), and run vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe from there.

there isn't a c:\localVSlayout directory

Your installer crashed for unknown reasons, and if you want to know the reason you may need to generate a dump file and analyze it, this will be very troublesome. It is recommended that you Delete the current installation files, then download the Visual Studio installer again from the official source. Here are the steps:
• Remove all with InstallCleanup.exe.
• Rerun the Visual Studio Installer bootstrapper. You might find the bootstrapper in your Downloads folder with a file name VisualStudioSetup.exe (Visual Studio 2022) or vs<edition>*.exe_ (Visual Studio 2019 and previous versions). Or, you can download the bootstrapper from the download pages for Visual Studio 2022 or Visual Studio 2019 and previous versions.
• Try to reinstall Visual Studio.

Here's how to run the InstallCleanup.exe tool:
• Open an administrator command prompt. 
• Enter the full path of the InstallCleanup.exe tool and add the command-line switch you prefer.
By default, the path of the tool is as follows("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\InstallCleanup.exe")  

refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#remove  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/installation/troubleshoot-installation-issues

There is no C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\ directory
